# Natbib does not display full author name

Tags: latex

I can't get natbib to display the full author name. Instead, I only get the last character. My document looks like so:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[sort, comma]{natbib}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}

According to \citet{Farmer2004}...

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{./refs}
\end{document}
```

The output of this is

```
According to r (a)
```

I am running Kile on Ubuntu 10.04, and my build order is PDFLatex, BibTex, PDFLatex,PDFLatex. I also tried building with TeXworks on both Ubuntu and Windows 7, result is identical. If I comment out natbib and use \cite instead of \citet, the output is

```
According to [Farmer(2004)]
```

The bib file looks like so:

```
\bibitem[Farmer(2004)]{Farmer2004}
Charles Farmer.
\newblock {Effect of electronic stability control on automobile crash risk.}
\newblock \emph{Traffic injury prevention}, 5\penalty0 (4):\penalty0 317--25,
  December 2004.
```

and the .aux file looks like so:

```
\relax 
\citation{Farmer2004}
\citation{Tseng1999}
\citation{Farmer2004}
\select@language{english}
\@writefile{toc}{\select@language{english}}
\@writefile{lof}{\select@language{english}}
\@writefile{lot}{\select@language{english}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}Introduction}{1}}
\newlabel{sec:intro}{{1}{1}}
...
\bibcite{Farmer2004}{Farmer(2004)}
```

...and some more citations below...
    \newblock ISSN 1538-9588.
    \newblock \doi{10.1080/15389580490896951}.
    \newblock URL \url{http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15545069}.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: I don't see any errors in your LaTeX, so could you please show the BibTeX entry for Farmer2004?

Comment: Exported by Mendeley:@article{Farmer2004,
abstract = {too long},
annote = {too long},
author = {Farmer, Charles},
doi = {10.1080/15389580490896951},
file = {path.pdf:pdf},
issn = {1538-9588},
journal = {Traffic injury prevention},
keywords = {Accidents, Traffic,Accidents},
month = dec,
number = {4},
pages = {317--25},
pmid = {15545069},
title = {{Effect of electronic stability control on automobile crash risk.}},
url = {http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15545069},
volume = {5},
year = {2004}
}

Comment: It would have been better if you'd edited the BibTeX entry into the answer.  But that, too, looks fine, so now I want to see excerpts of the .aux and .bbl files - whatever appears to be relevant.

Comment: Good point. Aux and bib biles shown above.

Comment: edited original post to include documentclass

Comment: I tried your example with TexLive on Ubuntu 10.10, and everything seems fine.  Can you (1) only use the minimal `.tex` and `.bbl` and use pdflatex on the command line to see if there is a problem in that case, and (2) give us the pdflatex/bibtex logs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you didn't include the information that you use newclude, because I ran into this error today with newclude and natbib

the answer is include newclude **before** natbib, then it works (for me)

\usepackage{newclude}
\usepackage{natbib}

Comment: Works for me also, had the same problem still in Kubuntu 14.10

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your help. In case someone else stumbles upon this question, the answer is "do not use package newclude".